# Blocking iOS Wi-Fi automatic update downloads?

Tags: ios, software-update, ipados

I've got several iPads connected to Verizon mifi devices(MiFi460LE)

iOS has a "feature" that automatically downloads OS updates in the background without user input. (You still need to manually install the updates, but the downloads happen automatically).

The 6.1 update may break the functionality of some in-house applications, and I'd rather not hand users an iPad with a flashing self-destruct button that tells users to "download now!"

Is there a specific port that could be blocked to prevent iOS OTA software updates? If that's not sufficient, would blocking hosts from DNS or another way of preventing these downloads be feasible?

Comment: I read that signing out of iCloud will stop this from happening; I have not tested it myself though.

Answer (score 2):

Without jailbreaking, or using an MDM (mobile device management) solution, you could just block the Apple site at your router. The site URL is `appldnld.apple.com`. All of Apple's IPSW files come from that location.

Comment: I'm going to ask a new question asking for MDM solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The latest update to the evasi0n jailbreak, evasi0n 1.2, allows you to disable OTA updates.

This is a fairly good tailored version of evasi0n considering the fact that it's the second update it received since it was released if you are hesitating about the down sides of jailbreaking on device performance.

Turning off iCloud might be a disadvantage. If you really want to disable OTA updates; I strongly suggest you to jailbreak.

[Here](http://imore.com/how-jailbreak-your-iphone-ipad-or-ipod-touch-ios-60-or-61-evasi0n) is a tutorial for jailbreaking with evaisi0n.

P.S. If you will download evais0n, ONLY download it from [evasi0n.com](http://evasi0n.com). Do NOT trust other sources.

Answer (score 1):

> Blocking iOS Wi-Fi automatic update downloads?

iOS/iPadOS 13.6 has introduced the ability for users to turn off automatic download of updates. To configure automatic download or installation of iOS/iPadOS updates on your iPhone or iPad, go to Settings app → General → Software Update → Customize Automatic Updates and toggle the switches as desired.

The linked Apple Support document discusses the same:

- https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204204

> #### Customize Automatic Updates
>
> [image: ios13-iphone-xs-settings-general-software-update-customize-auto-updates]
>
> With iOS 13.6, or iPadOS, you can choose not to download software updates automatically. Go to Settings > General > Software Update > Customize Automatic Updates, then turn off Download iOS updates.

Answer (score 0):

Apple's documentation says that the [automatic downloads only happen](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4623) when you are both:

- Plugged in to power
- Connected to Wi-Fi

It's not a long term strategy, but I have had people ensure they put their devices in Airplane mode before plugging in their devices to avoid a spike in downloads on release day for sites with fragile connections to the internet where we don't have more advanced options like blocking / throttling certain traffic as would be ideal for this situation.

Answer (score -3):

Just block the apple software sever...